# Don't have Title option on "Edit your profile" page on Russian Stack Overflow

Tags: support, profile-page, russian-stackoverflow, profile-edit

Can't find where I can set title on "Edit your profile" page on my Russian Stack Overflow profile.

On en SO:

> [image]

On ru SO:

> [image]

There is no such option at all.

What's the reason of that? Is it because Russian Stack Overflow doesn't have [Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is tied to Jobs. Other sites in the Stack Exchange network, like [the one you're currently on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current), don't have the option either.