# Title on Profile — Stack Overflow vs all other sites

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, jobs, profile-edit

It has [previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329786/317948) been [stated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315029/317948) that the Title feature is only present if the site has Jobs, but while Jobs has been completely gone for [over a year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/5306507), Stack Overflow profiles still show a Title, and it can be edited too.

I think it is a valuable thing to have on several sites (e.g. my job title is relevant on [PLDI](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/)), so I suggest adding Title to all sites (with an option of automatically propagating it, as with the rest of the propfile).